# CGContext difference in horizontal and vertical line width

Tags: ios, iphone, retina-display, cgcontext

Here is my code:

```
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5);

CGPoint hPoints[2];
hPoints[0] = CGPointMake(10, 21.5);
hPoints[1] = CGPointMake(100, 21.5);

CGContextAddLines(context, hPoints, 2);

CGPoint vPoints[2];
vPoints[0] = CGPointMake(10, 21.5);
vPoints[1] = CGPointMake(10, 41.5);

CGContextAddLines(context, vPoints, 2);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

And here is the result:

[image]

as you can see vertical line is exact 1px width but horizontal line is stretched. I've tried all possible values for Y - (20, 20.5, 21, 21.5) every time line is stretched.

I have read a lot of threads here but with no success, can someone explain what is happening and how can I draw horizontal line on retina display of exact 1px width?

upd:
Solved it by:

```
UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 0.5)]; 
[line setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; 
[self addSubview:line];
```

1retina px without any stretches!

Comment: Try not to use half points when drawing. Your vertical line is just a line of pixels. Your horizontal line is actually half way between two pixels and so it has to try and put half the line on each side.

Comment: figured out right now that vertical line also stretched by one px on Y axis. But every next stretched pixel merges with previous, as a result I have solid line. 
Half pixels does not matters, result the same.

Comment: Is that screenshot from a retina or non-retina display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, .5);

CGPoint hPoints[2];
hPoints[0] = CGPointMake(10, 22.0);
hPoints[1] = CGPointMake(100, 22.0);

CGContextAddLines(context, hPoints, 2);

CGPoint vPoints[2];
vPoints[0] = CGPointMake(10, 22.0);
vPoints[1] = CGPointMake(10, 42.0);

CGContextAddLines(context, vPoints, 2);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

If you draw a line and a point is a fraction then it will give a faint line. Hope this helps.. :)

**EDIT:**

Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html) you are looking for I think. Read **Points Versus Pixels**. It describe the problem you are facing.

Comment: vertical line became 2 retina px = 1 xcode px, and horizontal - 3px(1,5 xcode px), 1 opaque px in centre with semitransparent on top and bottom of it.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/2SqK5.png

Comment: in short - same result, it's stretched vertically for some reason but not horizontally.

Comment: "When stroked, the line straddles the path, with half of the total width on either side." This is the problem!! but even if I set 4 px width, there always will be one semitransparent hated pixel.

Comment: It seems like that. The thing with retina display is confusing.

Comment: F%$W$ that thing! Solved it by:         UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 0.5)];
        [line setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [self addSubview:line]; 1retina px without any stretches!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're drawing at 21.5 points.

When you use half a point it will try to place the line between two rows of pixels and to do this it tries to put half the line on each side (which obviously isn't possible) and so it draws a faint line on each side instead.

Just don't use half points and it will be fine.

Comment: Bill Dudney gives a very good and relevant explanation on points vs pixels in his WWDC 2011 talk Practical Drawing for iOS (session 129). It is really worth a view.